# .NET framework version 4.6.1 to 4.7 using current binary/web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks, target

I don't have source code to change the target framework and rebuild the solution.

I have only the web application (binary) that is already hosted in IIS Server. In the `web.config` I see

```
target framework="4.6.2"
```

and I want to change it to 4.7 or later version.

Is it possible to do change using only `web.config` file or any tools are available to change .NET Framework version to latest one?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Telerik JustDecompile` to convert your published version into source code.

`Telerik JustDecompile` is Open Source Decompilation Engine, [here](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) is a link to download it.

Once you have source code, you can change framework too.